# Mysql SP call with dynamic table name return null as result

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'am having following SP which return null when it call, but values are in the database

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calculate_amount_sum(IN accid INT UNSIGNED, IN tableName VARCHAR(100), IN tablecode VARCHAR(100), OUT calc FLOAT)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
SET @GetSql = CONCAT('SELECT SUM(amount) INTO @total FROM ', tableName, ' WHERE code=', ''' , tablecode, ''' , ' AND account_id=', accid);
PREPARE stmt FROM @GetSql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SET calc = @total; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempT (`amount` float(10,4) NOT NULL)  ;
INSERT INTO cache values (calc) ;    
INSERT INTO cache values (@total) ;    
END //
```

Error was

```
Column 'amount' cannot be null
```

when it insert values to tempT table

What can be the reason, Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code as below:

```
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(amount,0)) INTO @total FROM
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i changed it like this, then it fixed

```
 SET @GetSql = CONCAT("SELECT SUM(amount) INTO @total FROM ", tableName, " WHERE code='", tablecode,"' AND account_id=", accid);
```

Thanks